# Add leading zero to datetime value

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a easy question but hard to do for me. I have a date time value.

```
DateTime? Date;
```

Date has value like `4/2/2014`. How can i change this value to `04/02/2014`?

Comment: Convert it to a string, using correct format string (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Keep in mind that the value of a DateTime is just a datetime, it has no format.  The format is chosen when the date is displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format - it only gets a format when it's *displayed*.  If you don't specify a format (like when viewing in the debugger), a default one will be chosen depending on the control type and current culture.

So the right answer depends on *how* you're displaying the date.  If you're using `ToString`:

```
Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

If you're using some sort of control read the docs on how to specify value formats.

Answer (score -1):

here :)

```
dateTime thisDate = date.today.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");
```

you can also parse your string date like this

```
DateTime MyDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/2/2014")
string te = t.ToString("DD, MM, YYYY");
```